# Is there a simple ActionScript class that fetches the content from a URL and returns it?

Tags: actionscript-3, http, actionscript, fetch

Is there a standard class that simply returns the response received from a URL given a URL?

Looking through the documentation, I found mx.servicetags.HTTPService, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for.

**Update:** The request is happening inside of a function and therefore that same function has to return the result. In other words, callbacks aren't going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HTTPService` is specific to Flex. If you're looking for a pure actionscript-3 solution, use [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) with `URLRequest`.

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
ldr.load(new URLRequest(url));

function onLoad(e:Event):void
{
  var loadedText:String = URLLoader(e.target).data;
  trace(loadedText);
}
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that the data is being fetched inside a function and that same function needs to return the fetched data.

Comment: @George The loading process is asynchronous, you can't return the loaded data immediately. Move the remaining part of the calling function to the `onLoad` handler.

Comment: @George you wouldn't want to block until the page was loaded anyway - this would cause your Flash movie to freeze until the page was completely downloaded, which might take a while.

Comment: @Ender: Okay, I guess I'm stuck doing that :)

Comment: @George Don't forget to handle `ioError` and `securityError` - a detailed example is available in the linked page. You can load text, name-value pairs or binary data (check out `URLLoaderDataFormat` class).

Answer (score 0):

see sample code here: [Load an external text/html file using ActionScript 3, sample code](http://grfxguru.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/load-an-external-texthtml-file-using-actionscript-3-sample-code/)